# mustache template in Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mustache

I'm trying to get a mustache template to render in a rails view.

Here's what I did:

```
**Added to my gemfile:**
 gem "stache"
```

Then in my view:

```
<% @notifications.each do |n| %>
    <%= render "notifications/notification_item", n.attributes.symbolize_keys   %>
<% end %>

<%= template_include_tag "notifications/notification_item" %>
```

My mustache template is app/views/notifications/_notification_item.html.mustache

I get the following errors:

```
undefined method `attributes' for #<Hash:0x0000010749add8>
```

Ideas what I'm doing wrong? Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: +1, I don't think @notifications has AR instances in it...